# Xamarin HMACSHA512 VERY slow on Android

Tags: c#, security, xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-standard-2.0

I'm running the following code and for 10,000 iterations I get almost 5 seconds on Android (Samsung J5). On Windows (I5) for 100,000 iterations I get 200ms.

I can't test on Windows Mobile because the Xamarin project now targets .net standard which isn't compatible with Windows Mobile. But the actual app (which is an old one, using PCL) shows similar results - almost instantaneous on Windows Mobile and iOS, and a couple of seconds on Android, for the same code.

Is there a way to speed up HMACSHA512 (or its 256 version)?

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ICrypto crypto = DependencyService.Get<ICrypto>();
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

    byte[] b = new byte[64];
    watch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        b = crypto.CalculateHmac512(b);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    label.Text = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
}
```

And

```
class Crypto : ICrypto
{
    //HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256();
    HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512();

    public byte[] CalculateHmac512(byte[] m)
    {
        return hmac.ComputeHash(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you comparing device vs device, or device vs. emulator, or emulator vs emulator?  Do you really have a use case where you'll need to run this thousands of times at once on a device?

Comment: @Jason Device vs device. And yes, tens of thousands. While the user is waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's only *that* slow when connected to VS. When running independently it's faster.

For some reason, only Android suffers from this. UWP and iOS don't.